# Spotify: Client Upsell URL returns AccessDenied

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Today, while testing logon and logoff to Spotify via CocoaLibSpotify 2.4.2 (with libspotify-12.1.51-iOS), I have observed errors after entering user and password in SPLoginViewController:

Usually a upsell page is shown, but now there is only an "Access Denied" error shown.
URL causing issues is:
    http://libspotify.spotify.s3.amazonaws.com/client-upsell/client-upsell.html?userAgent=xyz&platform=iPhone&locale=de

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Thanks for the report — it looks like a simple permissions issue. It'll get fixed soon.